# Account for empty fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there a way to count empty fields with this query by adding somewhere Nz, IIf(IsNull()), or something similar?

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW
 mytable.[field1],
 mytable.[field2],
 mytable.[field3]

FROM mytable

WHERE (((mytable.[field1]) In (SELECT [field1] FROM [mytable] As Tmp GROUP BY

[field1],
[field2],
[field3]

HAVING Count(*)>1 And

[field1] = [mytable].[field1] And 
[field2] = [mytable].[field2] And 
[field3] = [mytable].[field3]
)));
```

returns nothing because there are *empty fields* in *field3*.

Is there a way to put

```
IIf(IsNull(field3), "emptyfield", field3)
```

or something similar somewhere in the query, so that empty field3's will be taken into account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count all the NULL values in all columns in an Access 2010 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555414/how-can-i-count-all-the-null-values-in-all-columns-in-an-access-2010-table)

Comment: @Rene: It is not about "counting" but to "account for".

Answer (score 0):

Try with one or two *Nz*:

```
Nz([field1], [mytable].[field1]) = [mytable].[field1]
' or:
[field1] = Nz([mytable].[field1], [field1])
' or:
Nz([field1], [mytable].[field1]) = Nz([mytable].[field1], [field1])

' or, if text:
Nz([field1], "") = Nz([mytable].[field1], "")
' or, if numeric:
Nz([field1], 0) = Nz([mytable].[field1], 0)
```